# str_replace not working with removing <br />

Tags: php, mysql

I have searched all over stackoverflow, and tried most of the techniques I have found.

However, mine are not working.

I have this string that was stored in my mysql database by using `nl2br()`. Now i want to get that string and display it.

```
$string =' This is a test<br /> <br />next line here.'
```

Things I have tried:

- All preg_match combos I could think of and found on stack overflow for removing breaks.
- `str_replace("<br />","\n",$string);`
- `str_replace("<br />",'\n',$string);`
- `str_replace('<br />',"\n",$string);`
- `str_replace('<br />','\n',$string);`
- `str_replace("<br />\r<br />","\n",$string);`
- `str_replace("<br />\n<br />","\n",$string);`
- `str_replace("<br />\r\n<br />","\n",$string);`
- `str_replace("<br />\n\r<br />","\n",$string);`

Also tried with `str_ireplace()`

All these combos do not work for me. The br still remains there and does not move.

I have spent hours on this and cannot think why this isn't working.

Thanks.

Comment: `str_replace("<br />","\n",$string);` works fine for me: https://3v4l.org/XXEGd

Comment: @Nick  nope, doesn't work.

Comment: Then there must be something in your string other than what is in your question, as I copy pasted that line into the demo, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
preg_replace("/<br\W*?\/>/", "\n", $your_string);
```